# How to install libarchive on macOS and make compiler will detect it?

Tags: macos, cmake, homebrew, clion, libarchive

I am trying to install libarchive on macOS for my school project. I tried to do it using brew formulae, but CMake says that it can't detect it. How can I install libarchive in the right way?

What I tried:
`brew install libarchive`

What I got in CLion:

```
  Could NOT find LibArchive (missing: LibArchive_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Comment: Please provide the *exact* error message in your question post. Also, please provide the specific commands you are running..

Comment: I added command and error, please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this GitHub [issue post](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/21415), `libarchive` isn't installed into the standard system paths. So, you'll need to tell CMake where to find it by setting the following in your CMake file:

```
set(LibArchive_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/local/opt/libarchive/include")
```

Note, you may have to modify the path here to match where `libarchive` was installed on your system

Comment: The only thing is include direcotry is not `*/libarcvhie/lib`, but `*/libarchive/include`.

Comment: @DenisIvanenko Thanks, I didn't have the archive in front of me, so just was going off of the GitHub issue post. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This works for Linux, macOS and macOS on Apple silicon.

```cmake
if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
    # Homebrew ships libarchive keg only, include dirs have to be set manually
    execute_process(
        COMMAND brew --prefix libarchive
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE LIBARCHIVE_PREFIX
        OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
        COMMAND_ERROR_IS_FATAL ANY
    )
    set(LibArchive_INCLUDE_DIR "${LIBARCHIVE_PREFIX}/include")
endif()
find_package(LibArchive REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE LibArchive::LibArchive)
```